# php code not executing. Checked config files already

Tags: php, javascript, apache

I have some php code in a seperate file and its being called using javascript. But the php code isnt working. instead its just putting the code in the div. Like the full code is in the div. how can i make this php code execute

My javascript function looks like this:

```
function checklogin(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
          if(xmlhttp.responseText='FAILED')
            {alert('failed');};
        }
      }

      var Usrname
      Usrname=document.getElementById("edtLoginUsername").text;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","DatabaseFunctions.php?Username="+Usrname,true);
    xmlhttp.send();};
```

AND MY PHP Code look like this:

```
<?php
      $myServer = "example.com";
      $myUser = "dbuser";
      $myPass = "dbpass";
      $myDB = "efarm"; 

      //connection to the database
      $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
        or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

      //select a database to work with
      $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
        or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

      //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username=myQuoteString('$_GET(USERNAME)')'"; 

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mssql_query($query);

      echo 'FAILED';
      //close the connection
      mssql_close($dbhandle);
      ?>
```

i have already checked my httpd.conf file and checked that the php is installed and configured

Comment: Did you try opening the PHP file in your browser and see if that works?

Comment: does browser show any error msg or any msg ?

Comment: And be very careful your code is vulnerable to SQL injections ... Do not use it in production /!\

Comment: my code seems to execute in the browser if i direct to the file directly. but it still doesn't seem to execute the code from the javascript, is there something wrong with my js code?

Comment: @Freelancer, the myQuoteString function replaces and prevents the injection, so if they try to inject code it will treat the whole username as a string still, but thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Well if you just treat the username as a string it's still vulnerable to SQL injections.. I suppose you wanted to say you escape all characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `MS SQL Connection` and use `$_GET['Username']` in place of `$_GET(USERNAME)`

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users 
         WHERE Username='".$_GET['Username']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
"...myQuoteString('$_GET(USERNAME)')'";
```

This is incorrect syntax for PHP. There are about five separate mistakes in just this tiny bit of code.

- `$_GET` is an array, not a function, so it needs square brackets, not round ones.
- `USERNAME` value inside the `$_GET` brackets is a string so must also be enclosed in quotes.
- `myQuoteString()` is a function call, which means it cannot be inside the query string.
- You've got quotes around `$_GET`, which is also incorrect.

Ouch.

I'll assume that `myQuoteString()` is a function you've written that escapes a variable for use in a SQL query and adds quotes?

In that case, your code needs to look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username=".myQuoteString($_GET['USERNAME']);
```

If `myQuoteString()` doesn't do all that, you need to make sure that either it does or you escape your input variable some other way, because you would be vulnerable to hacking attacks otherwise.

(if you're not sure, try posting your form with a name containing quote characters; if you're not escaping properly, that will cause the program to fail)

Hope that helps.